# Confused about the new bluetooth API createInsecureRfcommSocket() and pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth

In this past I've played with connecting two Android devices and every time they've required the user to input a pin to connect. I've even implemented the old "android-bluetooth" Google code project that attempted to inject the pin for a user-free connection without success after Android 1.5.

My question is, does the new 2.3.3 APIs allow for two Android devices to connect without user intervention? Not including NFC, is there anyway to allow phones to interact without authorization? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bluetooth version 2.1 and above has a new pairing mechanism called - Secure Simple Pairing (SSP), it allows for few different methods to pair , and it is different from the legacy pairing (which was the PIN entry mechanism). 
The new Secure simple pairing mechanism does not depend on user entered PIN, instead it has a generated 6 digit pass key.

One of the SSP mechanism allows for pairing without any intervention from the user. This method is called "Just-works" association model, the createInsecureRfcommSocket() API uses this method.

The other API createRfcommSocket() will use the other mechanism - passkey entry or user confirmation where the 6 digit passkey comes into play.

The new pairing will get used only when both devices are bluetooth 2.1 and above

I have a detailed description of the [new pairing mechanism here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401445/android-bluetooth-pairing/5408118#5408118)

Comment: Thanks. I noticed you wrote "just works" is used when there is no display or user interface available, but is there a way to use this method when there IS a display available(i.e. two android phones)? Is it as simple as listening on the socket created by createInsecureRfcommSocket()?

Comment: yes - the createInsecureRfcommSocket() will use the "just-works" model

Comment: Really useful. Can I use the `createInsecureRfcommSocket` method for all bluetooth devices?