# Error Connecting to Bluetooth on Acer Iconia B1

Tags: android, bluetooth

Thanks for looking at my question. I have developed a Bluetooth Application using a RN42 or HC05 Bluetooth Module on an Arduino. This is going to be a application i hope to put on the Play Store. The Application seems to work fine on most tablets i have checked it with apart from one (The one we want to use!) an Acer Iconia B1.

The Error i get from logCat is:

```
03-08 21:35:10.972: I/BluetoothSocket_MTK(2712): [JSR82] Bluetooth Socket Constructor
03-08 21:35:10.972: I/BluetoothSocket_MTK(2712): [JSR82] type=1 fd=-1 auth=false encrypt=false port=1
03-08 21:35:10.973: D/ActivityThread(1708): BDC-Calling finishReceiver: IIntentReceiver=41441d20
03-08 21:35:10.974: D/BTSocketService(402): [JSR82][Service] initSocket
03-08 21:35:10.974: I/BluetoothSocketService.cpp(402): [JSR82][JNI] initSocketNative +++.
03-08 21:35:10.974: I/BluetoothSocketService.cpp(402): [JSR82][JNI] initSocketNative: start to initialize socket.
03-08 21:35:10.975: I/BluetoothSocketService.cpp(402): [JSR82][JNI] type=1, auth=0, encrypt=0, port=1
03-08 21:35:10.975: I/BluetoothSocketService.cpp(402): [JSR82][JNI] initSocketNative: Initialize socket done.
03-08 21:35:10.975: E/BluetoothSocketService.cpp(402): [JSR82][JNI] No free context space; the APP has registered 20 services.
03-08 21:35:10.975: I/BluetoothSocketService.cpp(402): [JSR82][JNI] initSocketNative ---. fdHandle=0
03-08 21:35:10.975: D/Bluetooth(2712): ++++ Connecting to 00:12:05:22:95:84
03-08 21:35:10.975: D/BTSocketService(402): [JSR82][Service] connect
03-08 21:35:10.975: I/BluetoothSocketService.cpp(402): [JSR82][JNI] connectNative +++. fd=0.
03-08 21:35:10.975: E/BluetoothSocketService.cpp(402): [JSR82][JNI] connectNative: The FD (0) doesn't exist.
03-08 21:35:10.976: W/System.err(2712): java.io.IOException: [JSR82] connect: Connection is not created (failed or aborted).
03-08 21:35:10.976: W/System.err(2712):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:395)
03-08 21:35:10.976: W/System.err(2712):     at com.test.BluetoothConnection.connectBluetooth(BluetoothConnection.java:100)
03-08 21:35:10.977: W/System.err(2712):     at com.test.BluetoothCounter$1.run(BluetoothCounter.java:64)
03-08 21:35:10.977: W/System.err(2712):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-08 21:35:10.977: D/dalvikvm(2712): threadid=13: exiting
03-08 21:35:10.977: D/dalvikvm(2712): threadid=13: bye!
```

My Code to initialise the bluetooth:

```
   public boolean connectBluetooth() throws Exception, Exception{
        BT = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(MacAddress);
        m = BT.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocket", new Class[] { int.class });
        mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
        sock = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(BT, 1);
        Log.d("Bluetooth", "++++ Connecting to " + MacAddress);
        sock.connect();
        Log.d("Bluetooth", "++++ Connected");
        connected = true;
        in = sock.getInputStream();
        return true;
    }
```

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you're asking for a feature not present in the Acer Iconia B1.

The tablet is either not compatible with bluetooth 2.1 (first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613680/confused-about-the-new-bluetooth-api-createinsecurerfcommsocket-and-pairing)) or simply can't connect to devices other than "A2DP stereo headsets" (last post [here](http://community.acer.com/t5/Tablets/Acer-Iconia-B1-bluetooth/td-p/76703)).